# How to combine 2 mongoose models into 1

Tags: mongoose

I have 2 mongoose models and I am wondering how do I can issue a find query based on 2 models.

Here are the 2 models:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectID} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const govpersonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  personUUID: {type: String, required:true},
  personPrincipalName: {type: String, required:true},
  personEmail:{type: String, required:true},
  nameOfEmployer:{type: String, required:true},
  personRegisterDate: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
},{timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("GovPerson", govpersonSchema);





const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectID} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const pubpersonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  personUUID: {type: String, required:true},
  personPrincipalName: {type: String, required:true},
  personEmail:{type: String, required:true},
  personPassword: {type: String, required: true},
  personVerifyEmailToken:{type:String},
  personResetPasswordToken:{type:String},
  personResetPasswordTimeToken:{type:Date},
  nameOfEmployer:{type: String, required:true},
  personRegisterDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
},{timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("PubPerson", pubpersonSchema);
```

What I am doing in the NodeJS

//NodeJS

```
const GovPerson = require('../model/GovPerson');
const PubPerson = require('../model/PubPerson');
```

The problem I am facing now is how do I combine the 2 models into 1 so that I can query something like that

```
const person = await Person.findOne({personUUID: { "$eq": req.params.id } })
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear, please elaborate your question. what is the use of second model in first model?

Comment: hi turivishal, the second model has more properties than the first one. Both are independent as they are used to identify the type of person registered with us which is gov or pub. And since the person can be stored either in gov or public model and therefore I need to find out if the person exists or not by combining the 2 models into 1 so that I don't have to use if-else statement for example if this person does not exists in GovPerson then check if this person exists in PubPerson. Thanks

Comment: edit your question and add this details in your question, as per your comment i understand, this is not the right approach to query in 2 collections for one id, you can create a single collection and introduce a type field to store type of document.